# What would be the optimal way to rewrite this?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am looking for an optimal way to write this function.  Can anyone advise?

```
function increment($i) {
  $i += 1;
}
$j = 3;
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  increment ($j);
  echo "j = $j\n";    
}
```

output:

```
j = 3 
j = 3 
j = 3 
j = 3 
j = 3 
j = 3 
j = 3 
j = 3 
j = 3 
j = 3
```

Comment: *I am looking for an optimal way to write this function* ? Your code obsviously doesn't work properly (j is not incremented inside the for-loop). Do you want to optimize it or correct it ?

Comment: it does output, AHH, I see.  Thank you!

Comment: `return $i;` in the function would solve it, but it's not optimal.

Comment: What's wrong with `$j++;`? Calling a function to increment a basic int is a massive overhead compared to just incrementing it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment `$j` directly using `++`.

```
$j = 3;
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $j++;
  echo "j = $j\n";    
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `$j` in the for loop like this;

```
for ($j=3; $j < 13; $j++) {
  echo "j = $j\n";    
}
```

which is the optimal solution in terms of less code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you both for your input!  I have upped both answers and both comments.  @Adam Sinclair - you are right when it comes to the redundancy as common knowledge. however, I was looking for the most optimal solution.

Comment: So I awarded the answer to @worldofjr.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

Pass the variable by reference so the function can actually modify the value of it:

```
function increment(&$i) {
  $i += 1;
}
```

Here's the php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

---

This is if you want to modify a value in function without using return, otherwise you code would be more appropriate like that:

```
for ($j = 3; $j < 10; $j++)
  echo $j."\n";
```

Comment: This solution is far from optimal, extra overheads for a function that is redundant since `++` does the same thing!

Comment: @worldofjr who doesn't know that!! I assumed he wanted to experiment function passing the value by reference